# Printing Both Matching and Non-Matching Patterns

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to compare two files to then return one of the files columns upon a match. The code that I am using right now is excluding non-matching patterns and just printed out matching patterns. I need to print all results, both matching and non-matching, using `grep`.

**File 1:**

```
A,42.4,-72.2
B,47.2,-75.9
Z,38.3,-70.7
C,41.7,-95.2
```

**File 2:**

```
F
A
B
Z
C
P
E
```

**Current Result:**

```
A,42.4,-72.2
B,47.2,-75.9
Z,38.3,-70.7
C,41.7,-95.2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
F
A,42.4,-72.2
B,47.2,-75.9
Z,38.3,-70.7
C,41.7,-95.2
P
E
```

**Bash Code:**

```
while IFS=',' read point lat lon; do

check=`grep "${point} /home/aaron/file2 | awk '{print $1}'`

echo "${check},${lat},${lon}"

done < /home/aaron/file1
```

Comment: What should happen to a line in file 1 that doesn't have it's first column value present in file 2?

Answer (score 4):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{print ($1 in a?a[$1]:$1)}' file1 file2
F
A,42.4,-72.2
B,47.2,-75.9
Z,38.3,-70.7
C,41.7,-95.2
P
E
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F, '                  # field separator to ,
NR==FNR {                    # file1
    a[$1]=$0                 # hash record to a, use field 1 as key
    next
}
{
    print ($1 in a?a[$1]:$1) # print match if found, else nonmatch
}
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about order, there's a `join` binary in GNU coreutils that does just what you need :

```
$sort file1 > sortedFile1
$sort file2 > sortedFile2
$join -t, -a 2 sortedFile1 sortedFile2
A,42.4,-72.2
B,47.2,-75.9
C,41.7,-95.2
E
F
P
Z,38.3,-70.7
```

It relies on files being sorted and will not work otherwise.

Now will you please get out of my `/home/` ?

Answer (score 2):

another `join` based solution preserving the order

```
f() { nl -nln -s, -w1 "$1" | sort -t, -k2; }; join -t, -j2 -a2 <(f file1) <(f file2) | 
sort -t, -k2 | 
cut -d, -f2 --complement

F
A,42.4,-72.2,2
B,47.2,-75.9,3
Z,38.3,-70.7,4
C,41.7,-95.2,5
P
E
```

Cannot beat the `awk` solution but another alternative utilizing unix toolchain based on decorate-undecorate pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your current solution:
`1`. You are missing a double-quote in `grep "${point} /home/aaron/file2`.
`2`. You should start with the other file for printing all lines in that file

```
while IFS=',' read point; do
   echo "${point}$(grep "${point}" /home/aaron/file1 | sed 's/[^,]*,/,/')"
done < /home/aaron/file2
```

`3`. The grep can give more than one result. Which one do you want (`head -1`) ?
An improvement would be

```
while IFS=',' read point; do
   echo "${point}$(grep "^${point}," /home/aaron/file1 | sed -n '1s/[^,]*,/,/p')"
done < /home/aaron/file2
```

`4`. Using `while` is the wrong approach.
For small files it wil get the work done, but you will get stuck with larger files. The reason is that you will call `grep` for each line in file2, reading file1 a lot of times.
Better is using awk or some other solution.
Another solution is using `sed` with the output of another `sed` command:

```
sed -r 's#([^,]*),(.*)#s/^\1$/\1,\2/#' /home/aaron/file1
```

This will give commands for the second `sed`.

```
sed -f <(sed -r 's#([^,]*),(.*)#s/^\1$/\1,\2/#' /home/aaron/file1) /home/aaron/file2
```